# how to get results into array from unix commands

Tags: arrays, perl, unix, cat

I'm trying to get the dump of each file into an array from a unix command in a Perl script. below is the error I'm getting. Could anyone please help me fix this issue?

`Can't locate object method "cat" via package "C:/prac/cmm_ping.txt" (perhaps you forgot to load "C:/test/cmm_ping.txt"?) at fandd.pl line 25.`

below is my program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

@files=glob("C:/prac/*");

foreach $file (@files){
   @data=system(cat  $file);
      foreach $line (@data){`
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
system(cat $file)
```

contains an indirect method call. The above is equivalent to:

```
system($file->cat)
```

You meant

```
system("cat $file")
```

but that's wrong since you don't convert `$file` into a shell literal. It's best to avoid creating a shell command entirely by bypassing a shell you don't need anyway.

```
system('cat', $file)
```

Comment: when i used `system('cat',$file)` i'am getting the below `'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Do you have `cat`? If so, fix your path. If not, what do you expect?

Comment: Not sure if i'am following you..i see the values in the Loop for variable `$file` are coming with absolute path passing it to `cat` command.

Comment: Did you install `cat` on your machine? No version of Windows comes with it. Like you said, it's a unix tool.

Comment: ahh, that explains.. i was on windows machine trying to run the above code, So, what if i want use something DOS equivalent to stuff up the array in my code, what should i do?

Comment: `type` would do, but really, won't don't you just print the file using Perl? `open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!; print $_ while <$fh>;`

Comment: i've tried `open` to read and write, but i still have to do a check for specific string in the array for each file and write that line to a file. when i tried that i was getting the `if` conditions also written into data files(when i used regexps it was working fine). so, i switched  towards doing something like above. we'll see if i can have `type` to get to work or may be you suggest me asto how i can mask off the those `if` conditions dont creep into my destination file.

Answer (score 1):

I took a different route for the issue I was having about running the Unix commands in Perl, and I was able to figure that out with the below code.

```
@files = <C:/prac/*.ext>;

for $file (@files){
  open (FILE, "$file")             or die $!;
  open (OUT,">> C:/prac/data.txt") or die $!;

  while($line= <FILE> ) {
    print OUT $line if $line =~ /something/ ;
  }

  close FILE;
  close OUT;
}
```